# I want to override standard salesforce error message with my validation error message

Tags: validation

I have a field Water with data type Number and length is 5. so if it exceed more than 5 character, it is giving standard error message (Field limit exceeded) but need my validation error message(Max 5 characters) to display. Any help on this

Comment: make the field longer and add a validation rule to check that the value is not greater than 99999? Seems a bit weird to do so tbh

Answer (score 1):

As per salesforce order of execution, custom validation rules fires after the system validation rules.

Order of execution:

> 1. System Validation Rules
> 2. Apex Before Triggers
> 3. Custom Validation Rules
> 4. Duplicate Rules
> 5. Apex After Triggers
> 6. Assignment Rules
> 7. Auto-Response Rules
> 8. Workflow Rules
> 9. Processes
> 10. Escalation Rules
> 11. Roll-Up Summary Fields

In your case, you can't able to modify the standard validation error message.

Suggestion 1:

You need to increase the length of the `Water` field length and write a validation rule with expected error message. `In this case custom validation fires only if the value within the length you specified at field level.`

Example: `Water` field length = 18

If user enters the value within the 18 digits then custom validation will fire.

If user enters the value more than 18 digits then custom validation will not fire.

The validation formula will be like below.

```
LEN(Text(Water__C)) >5
```

Suggestion 2:

You can change the data type of water field from Number to Text and write validation rule to allow only 5 characters and it should contain only numeric values.

The validation formula will be like below.

```
 OR(NOT(ISNUMBER(Water__c)),
   LEN(Water__c) > 5
  )
```